# The current paper is the completion of the first paper

Tags: word-choice

I have submitted a paper to a journal. One of the reviewers is asking me what is the difference between the current paper and a previous paper I've written. In the 2nd paper I have completed the work mentioned in the previous paper. In fact the first one is a general idea and in the 2nd paper I have completed this idea.

How can I explain this? Should I say something like this:

> The current paper is the completion of the first paper.

Is there any better way to state this?

Comment: It might be better to say the current paper ***extends, builds on*** the first one (allowing for a possible *third* paper taking the ideas even further). But there's nothing wrong with ***is the completion***, even though obviously ***completes*** is more natural (that's why in your explanatory text you *twice* used the "active" verb form *I have **completed***; active phrasing is almost always more direct and easier to understand). Note that it's fine to say ***the paper*** completes the idea as an alternative to ***I*** (or ***we***, the author/s) complete the idea.

Comment: I would add some details in your rebuttal about what form the completion takes. Have you proved some new theorem? Have you done a further experiment which tested the hypothesis further? Reviewers and editors are busy people so give them as much help as you can. Depending on the form of completion @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica suggestion of extends may well be the word to choose.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a suitable response if you're looking for one line to explain the situation to your reviewer

> The current paper cements and solidifies my ideas and notions that were presented in the paper prior to this one.

Comment: I think that will lead to immediate rejection as the paper is supposed to advance over the old one not just rehash the ideas.